# <script> </script> tag doesn't work in repeater

Tags: jquery

I have some java script codes like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        TINY.box.show({ html: '<%# Eval("duyuru") %>', boxid: 'frameless', animate: true, width: 450, height: 350, autohide: 10 })
    </script>
```

it's opening a jquery window. "<%# Eval("duyuru") %>" contanins some html. if I add this code manually the window opening. but when I put same code in repeater or datalist or literal, its not working.

You can see it in my page source code. "right click and page source".

http://www.tomorhoca.com

code starts after line 244 with chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're injecting a newline into the `html` property, which is breaking the JavaScript:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        TINY.box.show({ html: '<a href="http://www.tomorhoca.com/canli-yayin"><img alt="" src="http://www.tomorhoca.com/canli8.jpg" /></a>
', boxid: 'frameless', animate: true, width: 450, height: 350, autohide: 10 })
    </script>
```

If that single quote that begins the second line were on the previous line, after the `</a>`, I think that would fix your error.

You might need to do a `String.Replace("\n", "")` or `String.Replace("\n", "<br />")` on that data before injecting it in the Repeater.

Comment: its fixed the line but still not working. thanks. its same print but i don't understand why don't work.

Comment: When I copy/paste line 254 to a console or text editor, I'm still seeing a line break. Removing it allows it to parse successfully at the console, but I get the illegal token error if I directly copy/paste. Strip out any `\r` characters too to be safe.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it like this

<%# Eval("duyuru").ToString().Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "") %>